# Conventional controller organisation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I just started to work with ASP.NET MVC, and I am quite lost about the use of controllers for static pages.

I won't have many pages, all of them will be static pages, except contact page I guess but I would like to get them well organised like :

Home page :
http://www.mywebsite.com/home/

Company pages :
http://www.mywebsite.com/company/about/
http://www.mywebsite.com/company/contact/

Then some legal pages :
http://www.mywebsite.com/legal/privacy-policy/
http://www.mywebsite.com/legal/cookie-statement/

Does it mean that I have to create 3 controllers ? HomeController, CompanyController and LegalController ? Or is managed from the routes ?
And are the Index actions mandatory ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As it sounds like a simple site, I wouldn't over complicate things with multiple controllers. Instead just keep with the default controller and decorate the actions instead.

For example:

```
[HttpGet("/Company/About")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

However if the site gets more complex then you may want to add controllers depending on the project. You'll then also probably have to revisit your routing strategy as a whole.

For more information on routing, see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#routing-basics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing